# Is there any way to exclude not needed locales (ngx-bootstrap/chronos) from build?

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I using `ngx-bootstrap` and datepicker. I found that there's a lot of not needed locales (~25 langs) definition in the final build that comes from `chronos` included by `ngx-bootstrap`:
`node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/locale/public_api.d.ts`

```js
export { arLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { bgLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { caLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { csLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { daLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { deLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { enGbLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { esDoLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { esLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { esUsLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { fiLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { frLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { glLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { heLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { hiLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { huLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { idLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { itLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { jaLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { koLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { ltLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { mnLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { nbLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { nlBeLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { nlLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { plLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { ptBrLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { roLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { ruLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { skLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { slLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { svLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { thLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { trLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
export { zhCnLocale } from 'ngx-bootstrap/chronos';
```

In my app I use only English language so I want to remove all additional locales definition from the final build.

Is there any way to do this expect forking repo and modifying the existing code?

Comment: Hi! are you sure they are being included in the final build(production)? Can you actually see the bundle including the langs?

Comment: I just checked the build with `--prod` and built optimizer set to `true` and it looks ok, i mean there is no unused languages! Thanks for giving a good point!

Answer (score 0):

All unused locales are removed when I run `--prod` build and build optimizer turned on.